# Is there a pdf form of documentation for Survey Connect?

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I found a paper for Updating field types in Survey123 and wonder if it comes from a larger volume .pdf source with more information documented.

Comment: A quick Google search shows that there is lots of documentation out there on Survey123. However, without more info we can't say anything about the specific pdf you're referencing. What have you tried and where are you stuck?